# ASP.NET MVC portals available?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

Is there an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) portal that is either commercially available or open source?

I am defining a portal as a [content management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) (CMS) where I can develop modules that can run from within the portal. Examples are [DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke), Mojo Portal, Drop Things, and Rainbow portal.

Comment: What you mean with "portal"? Please specify

Comment: @MicTech- I am guessing Zaff means something like DotNetNuke or Dropthings.

Comment: @MicTech, updated.. Apologies for being so Vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) are both done with ASP.NET MVC. ;)

And if by "portal" you mean "platform" like DotNetNuke, the only thing which comes to my mind is [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com).

Also you can check:

- [HydrogenCMS](http://www.hydrogencms.net)
- [Oxite](http://www.visitmix.com/Lab/Oxite)
- [N2](http://n2cms.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Oxite would be my choice. It got a bad reputation initially, but it has improved vastly since.

Answer (score 0):

I think ASP.NET MVC might be too much of a bleeding edge to have something of the sort at the moment, although having the membership API in place that leaves you with almost anything you need to get something up and ready yourself in almost no time, don't you think?